# Loading Banner Ads in View Controller With SKScene Glitches Game?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, iad, skscene

I'm currently developing a game where the objective is to survive as long as possible (i.e. Doodle Jump, Flappy Bird, Jetpack Joyride, etc) and there's no pause button. Anyways, I have a view controller that presents an SKScene. The moment I integrated banner ads, glitches began to occur.

For example, the game is good (fps is awesome) but as soon as banner ads low, it gets bad, the game drops to half the speed and its pretty hard to play. Obviously that's counter-productive.

I'm using a third party library called [LARSAdController](https://github.com/larsacus/LARSAdController) that alternates between iAds, Admobs, and Mopubs. Could it be something to do with threads? How can I call the ads on the main thread so that they don't glitch the game, or is that the opposite of what I should do? What's wrong here?

I have linked to the library, in case anyone is curious.

Comment: Guessing isn't going to help. You need to analyze the situation. Does the CPU usage go up, perhaps due to whatever the ad controller does? Or is it merely the ad being displayed that causes framerate to drop below 60 fps. If the game was just playing on the brink of dropping below 60 fps that may be the issue. Also note that iOS devices always redraw screens during vsync, so when the framerate drops below 60 it's going straight down to 30 fps.

Comment: Thank you for your kind and detailed response. I'll definitely check it. As of now, it looks like it stays at 60fps, but when loading mopub ads, it sometimes drops down to 42-47fps.